# Why does http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" only work for library Projects?

Tags: android, android-view

i read about the http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" namespace problems which where finally resolved in release 17 of the aapt tool. Beside the fact that an customview may have attributes i do not understand why an CustomView with no custom attributes cant be used when added as .jar file ? It only works for library projects. Why ?

There are some Android Projects which add the Views always manually because of this problematic, but why does the runtime not seem to be able to instantiate those components ? There seem to have valid constructors (Context context, AttributeSet attrs) like the com.jjoe64.graphview.BarGraphView

Anyone can make it more clear for me ?